# Cannot locate resource workflowdesigner.xaml When creating XAML Workflow Activity in Visual Studio 2010 using CRM 2011 SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-activity

It's very annoying problem, I tried to search everywhere for a solution, but nothing!
Anyway, I have installed the CRM 2011 SDK addin for visual studio 2010 (ultimate) and I am trying to create a XAML Workflow Activity

I have added the CRM Workflow items to the toolbox using these instructions: Add Microsoft Dynamics CRM Workflow Activities to the Toolbox

When I try and drop a Workflow on the design surface it say in red box text "Could not generate view for Workflow"

Hovering over the text reveals a System.IOException that says "Cannot locate resource workflowdesigner.xaml"

I read on another post to dump all the SDK bin folder files into the PublicAssemblies of the VS, but that didn't work for me! Tried that on a Windows 8, Windows Server 2008... Still nothing!!!

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

That is a known bug.  I contacted Microsoft and they confirmed it.  I was told to look for a fix in UR 17.  UR 16 was released in January so it should be out "soon".

Update Rollup history: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2555051/en-us

(I realize this is a late reply, but it was a recent issue for me.)